# How to properly subclass Promises with Babel and ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, babeljs, es6-promise

Usually using ES6 classes, it's pretty easy to composite classes like

```
class A extends B { /*...*/ }
```

When it comes to native, built-in classes like Promises though lots articles suggest avoiding subclassing. Babel itself significantly fails to transpile [such use cases](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1120). Is it somehow possible to properly transpile subclassing or even tune the example below?

PS I am using Rollup with [ES2015 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) and also tried to pipe the [transform-builtin-classes](https://github.com/WebReflection/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-classes) with my `.babelrc`

```
class P extends Promise {
  foo(func) {
    return this.then(func)
  }
  static bar(a) {
    return a
  }
}
```

Comment: Most browsers that support promises natively also do support ES6 classes, so you probably simply shouldn't transpile them at all.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to subclass `Promise`? I've never seen a good use case for it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Bergi @guest271314 I am trying to implement advanced flow control within a huge chain of async actions. The whole app is bundled with Rollup and transpiled via Babel . Actually, my goal is to provide utility functions such as Bluebird's `mapSeries` just natively .

Comment: Do you mean perform asynchronous procedures in sequence?

Comment: Notice that Bluebird is superior to Promise in terms of performance and several other aspects. Native doesn't mean better.

Comment: Given the small API surface area of promises, why not just compose them? Extending them don’t seem to provide any benefits. I.e. in your example you could just do `class P { constructor(handler) { this.promise = new Promise(handler); } foo(func) { return this.promise.then(func); } }`

Comment: @Theodore To implement `mapSeries`, you should simply write that helper function and export it from your module, no need to subclass `Promise` for that.

Comment: @Bergi Moreover, all the good stuff had already been written https://github.com/sindresorhus/promise-fun#packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are obstacles for built-in classes inheritance in ES5 that can sometimes be avoided by using a combination of `Reflect.construct` and `Object.setPrototypeOf` as a workaround. This is a method that is used by Babel [`transform-builtin-classes`](https://github.com/WebReflection/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-classes/blob/v0.4.0/src/index.js#L7-L17).

The fact if this method is applicable depends on how built-in class works. In case of `Promise` this may require to additional intermediate class that inherits from built-in, then it can be inherited using regular `class ... extends`.

```
function _P(executor) {
  return Reflect.construct(Promise, [executor], P);
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(_P, Promise);
_P.prototype = Object.create(Promise.prototype);

class P extends _P {
  static bar(arg) {
    return new this(resolve => resolve(arg));
  }

  foo(...fns) {
    return this.then(...fns);
  }
}
```

This establishes [correct prototype chain](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAfQAoAoCmAPTERRwBOAlIgN4BQiiRmUIRSASpsADZ5QB0ECAzlCIho6VETgBbGP0wAaRAG0ceAsQC6C1CQDclAL6VKabgAcJhKAE9TmRAF5EAeQBGAKy686AQyiYxEtKyZhZw1ra6lK4e0NyyUOJhYTaYTsDoaFqBMpiRlBDs3vz8iKiIOH5gACYlaBTUiIK-MBCILt5E6B0A5mRUNDR0DEyIYJgA7ohQABYy6HT8cOwAbnb2AHy0mIsr_j0kkTSGDcBwcOjcl8Bg_H0Ng_SMSDMy3DOYYBdXN4eIhsd8G5LTDcdhwbroBoAcnMSXCdgg028MCQMkQfCIdGgULkDTGkww6DIGwo-hIvAEQhEhCI3DA3kk8hoeImpXQRIcm3IZMQKKakEwcGApWyslxNHxbI5JO5ZD5UG8AqFpXFpW4CyWqyJ3FO52lXJ58sVEEFwsSQXkDVQ6u2mv85N17OJBrlNwVSrNzMiQA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&version=6.26.0). The downside of this method is that it is hard-coded to `P` subclass that will be hard to extend further.

A cleaner way to do this is to make intermediate class wrap built-in class instance. This requires to replicate original class API in intermediate class, but since it is small, this is an acceptable trade-off for prototype chain that has no limitations:

```
function _P(executor) {
  this._promise = new Promise(executor);
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(_P, Promise);
_P.prototype = Object.assign(
  Object.create(Promise.prototype),
  {
    then(...args) {
      return this._promise.then(...args);
    },
    ...
  }
);

class P extends _P { ... }
```

It should be noticed that this functionality is already available via [promise ponyfills](https://github.com/sindresorhus/promise-fun#packages) already, including [`mapSeries`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-map-series). Using them as self-contained helper functions is generally a preferable alternative to `P` subclass, considering that every native promise should be converted to `P` promise with `P.resolve` in order to benefit from additional functionality.